# PHP fseek with remote files

Tags: php, file, fseek

I want to read remote file from the end but fseek doesn't support remote files. Is there way to make this?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own [streamwrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php). Or copy the whole file locally and fseek on that.

Answer (score 0):

you should try cURL . it should get the job done. 
u just need to check if CURL is installed on ur web server.